# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 

file = 'D:/myproject/chatbot_database.xlsx'
xl = pd.read_excel(file)
print(xl)                                        #this prints fine     
print(xl.iloc[0, 1])                             #this throws an error
```

***The error message is:***

> AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute
>   'iloc'

I have tried searching through stackoverflow and googled this for 2 days but i just don't seem to be able to get an answer so i am posting this question. So the main issue is that this code works on my computer but it does not work on my friends computer. I tried to reinstall pandas hoping that that would fix the iloc issue since iloc is part of pandas but no avail. Anyone has any idea what the issue is? or what other libraries may be missing?

> **Edited post below with screenshot below**

[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: check `print( type(xl) )` . If `xl` is really `'collections.OrderedDict'` then it doesn't have method `iloc`. You would have to convert to `DataFrame` which has `iloc`

Comment: first you should find documentation for `read_excel` and check if there is no information about needed modules.

Comment: @furas to read xls/xlsx pandas need `xlrd` module, but there will be an error at `read_excel()` if this module is missing

Answer (score 1):

Reason is you forget mentioned `sheet_name=None` parameter in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), what return `OrderedDict`, where keys are sheetnames and values are DataFames:

> **sheet_name** : str, int, list, or None, default 0
>
> Strings are used for sheet names. Integers are used in zero-indexed sheet positions. Lists of strings/integers are used to request multiple sheets. Specify None to get all sheets.
>
> Available cases:
>
> Defaults to 0: 1st sheet as a DataFrame
> 1: 2nd sheet as a DataFrame
> "Sheet1": Load sheet with name “Sheet1”
> [0, 1, "Sheet5"]: Load first, second and sheet named “Sheet5” as a dict of DataFrame
> **None**: All sheets.

```
xl = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
```

Comment: Added that in. I have made an edit to my original post please have a look at the error messages in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

1. first of all please put the exact error message.
2. print(type(df)) it should return `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` not 
   `'collections.OrderedDict'`
3. while reading mention sheetname `pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, sheet_name=sheet1)` or `pd.read_excel(file.xlsx, sheet_name=None)` if no sheet name provided
4. Please go through documentation of any modules before using it

Comment: Edited my post above with screenshots have a look please thanks! i just have no idea why my computer is able to show a result while on my friends computer that is just not working out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```py
df = pd.read_excel("my_spreadsheet.xlsx", sheet_name="name_of_sheet")
```

Where "name_of_sheet" is the name given to the single sheet in the file. I had removed 3/4 sheets from my file and saved it with just a single sheet and I thought that the default behaviour would be to load just a single sheet into the dataframe. In fact the behaviour is that an ordered_dict is created with one entry - the named sheet in the xlsx.