# AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: python, count, attributeerror

I'm receiving an error message and can't seem to figure it out.  It happens when I try to count the number of instances the value 0 occurs in ws1 column F starting at row 4, and then write it out to ws3 column M row 2. Has anyone encountered this error before?

```
Error
    counts = series.value_counts()

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

import openpyxl as xl 
import os
import pandas as pd 
  
input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
template = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\template.xlsx'
summary = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\summary.xlsx'
newFile = 'Comparison.xlsx'
  
  
  
  
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]
  
  
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0] 
  
i=0
ii=0
  
  
for file in files: 
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]
    
   series = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheetname=None, skiprows = [5], usecols = "F", squeeze = True) 
   counts = series.value_counts()
   z = counts[0]
     
   wb2 = xl.load_workbook(summary) 
   ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
  
      
   ws3[f'A{i+2}']=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
   ws3[f'D{i+2}']=ws1['B4'].value
   ws3[f'E{i+2}']=ws1['D4'].value
   ws3[f'I{i+2}']=ws1['B'][-1].value
   ws3[f'J{i+2}']=ws1['D'][-1].value
   ws3[f'O{i+2}']=ws1['E'][-1].value 
   ws3[f'N{i+2}']=ws2[f'I{ii+6}'].value  
   ws3[f'M{i+2}']=z 
   i += 1
   ii +=1          
     
     
  
   wb3.save(newFile)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'iloc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59213846/attributeerror-collections-ordereddict-object-has-no-attribute-iloc)

Comment: One more bug. It should be `usecols=["F"]`

Comment: When I correct usecols=["F"] I receive error ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['F'].  This is strange because my excel files have column F data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `sheet_name=None`, you'll get a `dict` object not a `Series` or `DataFrame`object.

And a `dict` object does not have the method `.value_counts()`.

In ur case , u could do like this:

```
 series = pd.read_excel(input_file, sheetname='ur_sheet_name', skiprows = [5], usecols = "F", squeeze = True)
```

Or:

```
series = pd.read_excel(input_file,skiprows = [5], squeeze = True)['title_of_column_F']
```